# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, rpy2

Here, I tried to call R function from python code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

time_series_data = pd.read_csv(daily_file_path, sep=",", header=None).values
nr,nc = time_series_data.shape
r_time_series_data = ro.r.matrix(time_series_data, nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
ro.r.assign("r_time_series_data", r_time_series_data)
```

When I imported R library, it throws an error given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 4.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 4.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1023, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 4.0\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/nca150130/PycharmProjects/anomaly/src/test/test4.py", line 26, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as ro
  File "C:\Users\cc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Users\cc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    _load_r_dll(R_HOME)
  File "C:\Users\cc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 29, in _load_r_dll
    ctypes.CDLL(r_dll)
  File "C:\Users\cc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I tried to add dll files that R uses to `PATH` environment. Still, I am getting this error. Can you please give me any suggestions?